# Automator adding dots when I write code

Tags: automator, javascript-automation

When I type some code in the **Run JavaScript** box in Automator, it’s always adding a few dots, sometimes replacing what I’m typing.

This also happens with **Run AppleScript**, but not with **Run Shell Script**. I think it’s trying to second-guess what I’m typing, but I can’t work out what it’s thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is [code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion), where it is trying to match what you are currently typing to what you have typed before.  The idea is to avoid typos and speed up the entry of common terms.  The items it keeps track of tend to be language keywords and items that you have previously entered, such as function and variable names.

Different editors can use various key combinations and/or implement snippets, substitutions, or not do anything.  My guess is that the **Run Shell Script** action doesn’t bother since shell scripts typically use short or single character terms, so it would probably get in the way more than it is worth.

The way it works in the **Run JavaScript** and **Run AppleScript** actions is if there is only one match to what you are currently typing, it will be shown in light gray, and pressing the escape key will enter that text and move the cursor to the end.  The dots mean that there are multiple possibilities, and it is waiting for more characters before it can make a match.  You can continue typing, but pressing the escape key will pop up a list of possible guesses that you can choose from.  Arrow keys will navigate the items, return will enter the selected item, and escape will dismiss the dialog.

Comment: The problem is that it’s gone wild. It replaces what I’m typing with the dots, and I can’t seem to stop it. Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: @Manngo  Editors such as Xcode and Script Editor have a preference setting, but I haven’t found anything for Automator.  You might try copying the text and pasting it into a fresh workflow to reset the context.